# Not able start DSE-5.1.7, Log showing GC stats without starting Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, garbage-collection, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

```
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:38:32,553  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 205ms.  G1 Eden Space: 2965372928 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 400556064 -> 448790568; G1 Survivor Space: 205520896 -> 264241152;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:38:36,675  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 250ms.  G1 Eden Space: 3422552064 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 448790568 -> 534773792; G1 Survivor Space: 264241152 -> 293601280;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:38:39,871  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 241ms.  G1 Eden Space: 3254779904 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 534773792 -> 612368424; G1 Survivor Space: 293601280 -> 310378496;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:38:44,093  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 275ms.  G1 Eden Space: 3636461568 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 612368424 -> 713031720; G1 Survivor Space: 310378496 -> 327155712;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:38:49,379  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 310ms.  G1 Eden Space: 4387241984 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 713031720 -> 832569376; G1 Survivor Space: 327155712 -> 356515840;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:38:55,146  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 343ms.  G1 Eden Space: 4794089472 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 832569376 -> 922746920; G1 Survivor Space: 356515840 -> 436207616;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:38:58,869  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 336ms.  G1 Eden Space: 2956984320 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 922746920 -> 1189085216; G1 Survivor Space: 436207616 -> 268435456;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:39:04,369  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 284ms.  G1 Eden Space: 4882169856 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 1189085216 -> 1186988072; G1 Survivor Space: 268435456 -> 427819008;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:39:08,836  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 342ms.  G1 Eden Space: 4072669184 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 1186988072 -> 1356857376; G1 Survivor Space: 427819008 -> 377487360;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:39:14,653  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 357ms.  G1 Eden Space: 4773117952 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 1356857376 -> 1457520688; G1 Survivor Space: 377487360 -> 444596224;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:39:20,333  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 389ms.  G1 Eden Space: 4706009088 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 1457520688 -> 1619001384;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:39:26,030  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 386ms.  G1 Eden Space: 4706009088 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 1619001384 -> 1736441896; G1 Survivor Space: 444596224 -> 490733568;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:39:31,146  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 397ms.  G1 Eden Space: 4659871744 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 1736441896 -> 1906311216; G1 Survivor Space: 490733568 -> 465567744;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:39:36,410  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 385ms.  G1 Eden Space: 4685037568 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 1906311216 -> 2067791912; G1 Survivor Space: 465567744 -> 452984832;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:39:43,245  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 401ms.  G1 Eden Space: 4697620480 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 2067791912 -> 2233466928; G1 Survivor Space: 452984832 -> 448790528;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:39:49,358  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 386ms.  G1 Eden Space: 4584374272 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 2233466928 -> 2376073264; G1 Survivor Space: 448790528 -> 465567744;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:39:55,028  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 406ms.  G1 Eden Space: 4408213504 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 2376073264 -> 2684354600; G1 Survivor Space: 465567744 -> 310378496;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:40:00,316  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 290ms.  G1 Eden Space: 4412407808 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 2684354600 -> 2841641008; G1 Survivor Space: 310378496 -> 281018368;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:40:05,867  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 274ms.  G1 Eden Space: 4311744512 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 2841641008 -> 2841641512; G1 Survivor Space: 281018368 -> 423624704;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:40:11,147  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 360ms.  G1 Eden Space: 4026531840 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 2841641512 -> 2992635936; G1 Survivor Space: 423624704 -> 406847488;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:40:16,618  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 351ms.  G1 Eden Space: 3913285632 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 2992635936 -> 3258974248; G1 Survivor Space: 406847488 -> 276824064;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:40:21,549  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 286ms.  G1 Eden Space: 3904897024 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 3258974248 -> 3403677728; G1 Survivor Space: 276824064 -> 272629760;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:40:26,446  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 272ms.  G1 Eden Space: 3770679296 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 3403677728 -> 3537895456; G1 Survivor Space: 272629760 -> 264241152;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:40:29,829  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 255ms.  G1 Eden Space: 3653238784 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 3537895456 -> 3676307488; G1 Survivor Space: 264241152 -> 222298112;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:40:34,831  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 236ms.  G1 Eden Space: 3598712832 -> 0; G1 Survivor Space: 222298112 -> 343932928;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-07-31 09:40:39,021  GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 294ms.  G1 Eden Space: 3355443200 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 3676307488 -> 3806330912; G1 Survivor Space: 343932928 -> 335544320;
```

Comment: How do you see that it doesn't start? what do you have in the log before the GCInspector lines?

Answer (score 0):

Do you check if you have a huge partition key?

Comment: Yeah, I checked. There are no huge partitions.